# Possible mysql database table structure for parent child relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

I have one examination question:
My name is D. I am the dad of three chrildren, A, B and C. I have a parent Z. My parent has a parent X and I have a brother, Y. I am stored in a Mysql DB.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_tree` (
`idperson` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`prime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`product` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idperson`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

INSERT INTO `temp`.`test_tree`
(`idperson`,
 `name`,
 `prime`,
 `product`)
 VALUES
 ('1', 'x', '2', '2'),
 ('2', 'z', '3', '6'),
 ('3', 'y', '17', '102'),
 ('4', 'd', '5', '30');
```

NOTE: Prime and products are used to calculate the parent child relationship of my family.
Prime = next available prime number
Product = (prime * product of parent). Each product of primes can only be divided by those primes.

**Question: What are the other ways that could be used to create a tree and how do they compare to the current solution?**

My ans:

```
Solution 1:
**test_tree**
-id pk
-parent_id fk (references id)
-name

Solution 2:
**person**
-id pk
-name

**relation**
-child_id fk (references person.id)
-parent_id fk (references person.id)

For me, solution 2 has redundant table.
```

Can u suggest me other ways to create table for such relation?

Comment: The way you suggested is the way I would do it.

Comment: thanks but the question also says :max 3 alternatives.so there must be other solutions isnt it?

Comment: sure you could store the relations in a separate table as well, which would probably be more appropriate if you had more complex relationships you had to map. Or my favorite would be to store the tree structure in a NoSQL database, in which case you case store an object representation of the tree in it's entirety.

Comment: please look at the updated question. could that be solution 2?

Comment: Yes your solution two is what I was talking about.  Like I said, if I was using a relational database for this, I would use solution 1, but solution 2 is another approach and could actually be a better one if you wanted to define a number of more complex relations directly (i..e person_id, parent_id, grandparent_id, etc.)  to me it would depend on how the application needed to access the tree relations.

Answer (score 1):

You've omitted the "Nested Set Model" for representing a hierarchy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

---

The wikipedia article provides an example, as well as links to other references with plenty of examples.

Comment: can u give one sample solution for this question with the above question?